# minus sign in JS code

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys i am new to js and basically i am also learning jquery , i just need some help decoding some simple js syntax , look below :

```
function pencilPartsHandler() {
    pencilY = -($pencil.offset().top - ($win.scrollTop() + $win.height()));

    $parts.each(function() {
        var $part = $(this);

        movePart($part);
        fadeText($part);
    });
}
```

now the line thats confusing me is this perticular one , `pencilY = -($pencil.offset().top - ($win.scrollTop() + $win.height()));`, why the minus sign in the beginning?

is it just because , whatever value evaluates out of `$pencil.offset().top - ($win.scrollTop() + $win.height())` should be a negative or is there something more then meets the eye ??

Thank you.

Comment: No, nothing more behind it. It's simply a unary operator that returns the negative value.

Comment: It's just the mathematical negation of a value. Why it's being done in this particular case is impossible to say without more context.

Comment: @Pointy , thanks , that's all i wanted to know !! so the author if this code , intents the value of `pencilY` to be a negative , at all times ?

Comment: Mathematically, could also be a positive number

Comment: @Tenali_raman: That's not what the operator does. It changes the sign of the operand, it doesn't make it negative regardless of the sign that it had.

Comment: @Mircea , how are u talking about the minus + minus = plus rule ?

Comment: @Guffa , you guys are being helpful , but are confusing me :(

Comment: @Tenali_raman it means that `pencilY` will be negative when that expression has a positive result, and positive when the expression has a negative result. That is, it means that `pencilY` will have the **opposite** sign of that expression.

Comment: @Pointy , what u just said compliments guffas answer and thats the answer i was looking for . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [unary negation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_negation) changes the sign of the operand. I.e. if `x` is positive then `-x` is negative, and if `x` is negative then `-x` is positive.

The expression is just the same thing as:

```
pencilY = $win.scrollTop() + $win.height() - $pencil.offset().top;
```

So that puts `pencilY` at `($pencil.offset().top)` pixels from the bottom of the screen.

Comment: thanks alot , can u just add a few words about what is , changing the sign of an operand ??

Comment: @guffa so whatever `$pencil.offset().top - ($win.scrollTop() + $win.height())` returns as the result , the minus sign in the beginning turns it into  the opposite ? is it ?

Comment: @Tenali_raman: I added a bit more information about the operator.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik: Exactly, if by opposite you mean a sign change. For example from `-420` to `420`.